# sessionState problem at .net mvc (MySQL)

Tags: asp.net, mysql, session-state, session-cookies

Have next problem: i setup the custom session state server (store sessions in Mysql). But the session data not added to database (the default .net session table is empty), but the authorization works (!). If I change the coockieless option to true, the session data start to add to database (but i dont want to use coockieless=true).

Sometimes I think that the framework choose what to use: inproc or my custom store...

My Config:

```
<sessionState mode="Custom" cookieless="false" timeout="20" customProvider="MySqlSessionStateStore">
      <providers>
        <add name="MySqlSessionStateStore" type="MySql.Web.SessionState.MySqlSessionStateStore, MySql.Web, Version=6.3.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" applicationName="/" description="" connectionStringName="MySqlMembershipConnection" writeExceptionsToEventLog="False" autogenerateschema="True" />
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <membership defaultProvider="MySqlMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="MySqlMembershipProvider" type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.3.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" applicationName="/" description="MySQL default application" connectionStringName="MySqlMembershipConnection" writeExceptionsToEventLog="False" autogenerateschema="True" enablePasswordRetrieval="False" enablePasswordReset="True" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="False" requiresUniqueEmail="True" passwordFormat="Hashed" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <profile defaultProvider="MySqlProfileProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="MySqlProfileProvider" type="MySql.Web.Profile.MySQLProfileProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.3.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" applicationName="/" description="" connectionStringName="MySqlMembershipConnection" writeExceptionsToEventLog="False" autogenerateschema="True" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="MySqlRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="MySqlRoleProvider" type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLRoleProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.3.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" applicationName="/" description="" connectionStringName="MySqlMembershipConnection" writeExceptionsToEventLog="False" autogenerateschema="True" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <connectionStrings>
    <add name="photostorageEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Photos.csdl|res://*/Models.Photos.ssdl|res://*/Models.Photos.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=ip;User Id=user;password=pass;Persist Security Info=True;database=photostorage; Charset=utf8&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="MySqlMembershipConnection" connectionString="Data Source=ip;userid=user;password=pass;database=photostorage;Charset=utf8" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Your code looks correct. What do the logs say? Try setting writeExceptionsToEventLog="true" and checking those. The guide at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-tutorials-asp-roles.html suggests changing some machine.config values instead of doing it in the web.config. I don't know that library well though--I'm not sure if that will matter or not. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed using separated connection string for Sessions (I don't know why it's not working in other way)